# Java: Multiplication table string needs to be modified to get spaces in between each character

Tags: java, string

So im trying to make a string in java that displays a multiplication table with a tab in between each number in Java. Im looking for the modifier that adds more spaces between EACH CHARACTER.
Heres is my code that I have done and now I need to modify the table of strings to have spaces in between each number like "1   2   3   4" instead of "1 2 3 4".

```
    import java.util.*;


public class MultTable
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String y = ("1 23 " + "12345");


 System.out.println("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10");
 System.out.println("2 4 5 8 10 12 14 16 18 20");
 System.out.println("3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30");
 System.out.println("4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40");
 System.out.println("5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50");
 System.out.println("6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60");
 System.out.println("7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70");
 System.out.println("8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80");
 System.out.println("9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90");
 System.out.println("10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100");



}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            System.out.print(i*j + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

If you want more space between numbers, just add it to the first System.out.print()
To add a tab use the scape sequence "\t"

Comment: I know I could just add spaces in the string but its for school and we are using becker robots and I literally stuggle to learn anything from the book.

Comment: and the course is centered around the book so im getting really frustrated.

Comment: use "\t" to add a tab

Comment: yes thank you, even though you gave me the answer now I finally understand so its more helpful than me struggling and not getting it done.

Answer (score 0):

If You have already the List You can simply replace each space with some for example tab like this:

```
System.out.println("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10".replaceAll("\\s","\t"));
```

and the result:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```